# Django ArrayField not storing data properly

Tags: django, postgresql

I stumbled up strange issue today, I could not properly add item to ArrayField() in django.
The document is straight forward: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#arrayfield

Here is my model:

```
class AppealStateChangeLog(models.Model):

agent = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='appeal_change_log_appeal_id',
    )
codes = ArrayField(
        models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True),
        default=list
    )
```

I could not add codes like this

```
# some where in code
codes = ['11111','22222','33333']
c= AppealStateChangeLog(
       agent=appeal.agent,
       codes=[str(a) for a in codes] if codes else []
      )
c.save()
```

This code only adds `['11111']` in codes field, I was expecting all three values.

The strange things is when I try to update the values it updates successfully as:

```
item = AppealStateChangeLog.objects.get(id=123)
codes = ['11111','22222','33333']
item.codes = codes
item.save()
```

This stores all three values.

I even tried to create using AppealStateChangeLog.objects.create() method but it only add first value of the array i.e ['11111'].

Postgres version: 12
django version: 1.10 (it's an old system I know :) )